# Products are not shown when update the product category?

Tags: magento-1.7, products, category-products

I assign a default category to show in my home page.
Ex.All Deals.

When i edit the All Deals category from the admin panel the products belongs to that category are not shown in the home page and home page shows the **coming soon** message.
I again go to each product and assign the category.

All the live products belongs to that category unchecked.

If any one meet the same issue can you  please explain what is happening?

**magento version 1.7**

Comment: After assigning products have you checked if you need to reindex?

Comment: I did not reindex. its shows the all products automatically.

Comment: Mm dont quite understand what shows all products? Also how have you added products to display on your homepage

Comment: I assigned the Default Web URL to the specific category to display in home page in configuration->General->web->Default pages.